# Is it possible for a DCGAN to do regression? What are some examples of this?

Tags: gan

I'm currently a student doing some machine learning projects, and I want to use generative adversarial networks to train some data to discern for example, how old someone is. The intended output is a regression continuous output in term of months.

I see the DCGANs and GANs are targeting mainly classification problems. Can they be used to solve regression problems?

Thank you.

Comment: GANs are not targettting classification problems. They are generative models, so their purpose is to generate data, usually images.

Comment: @ncasas thanks, I just realized this, that the purpose of classifying was to get the generator's output as close as possible to the "real" images.

Comment: Semi-supervised Biomedical Translation with Cycle Wasserstein Regression GANs http://www.marzyehghassemi.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/semi-supervised-CWR-GAN_Ghassemi.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.  There is a paper Intra-class Variation Isolation in Conditional GANs (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.11296.pdf) discussing it.

They propose a "C-GAN that is able to learn realistic models with continuous, semantically meaningful input parameters".  They actually cover generating images of people at different ages as well.

Comment: The article you linked has nothing to do with regressions, as the OP asked

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to train a Convolutional regression model, and train it adversarially. So in theory you can. @Zhongsheng Chen linked a case of a Conditional GAN used for regression, even though I didn't find DCGANs for this, specifically.

In other words: it is possible in theory, but in practice using very large and heavy models such as GANs to run a regression is a like killing moquitoes with a bazooka.

Answer (score 0):

I am also interesting about it. Recently, I found a paper which the authors used a conditional GAN for regression tasks, in hope it will drive you over this problem. For a detail about this paper, see [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Regression-with-Conditional-GAN-Aggarwal-Kirchmeyer/5922060eb37760c6e7c95e06019ae13282b9bb40).